# Highcharts highstock x axis max/min not working with 3+ data elements

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a some time interval that has to be shown on chart. The task is to show entire interval, no matter if it has full data or just some part.
For this I try to use `xAxis: {
    min: ...
    max: ...
  }`

It works perfectly with 1 or 2 data elements [https://jsfiddle.net/pavlo0483/crobg7v2](https://jsfiddle.net/pavlo0483/crobg7v2/).

But not working with 3+ elements [https://jsfiddle.net/pavlo0483/4v5yxorg](https://jsfiddle.net/pavlo0483/4v5yxorg/).

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: Try to disable ordinal axis - https://jsfiddle.net/bzbgrL7t/

Comment: Wow! Lightning fast answer. And it works!
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

As morganfree commented, for this ordinal axis has to be disabled

```
xAxis: {
    ordinal: false,
    ...
}
```